# One of my JavaScript variables seem to be getting reset after a jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My code sends requests to Twitter for search data gets responses in the from of JSON. After getting the JSON, it stores the count of responses that match a certain condition in an array.

Here is the code that makes the call to the function that queries Twitter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
graph = new HighCharts.chart({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                console.log("events.load");

                var that = this;
                var update = function() {
                if (polling) {
                    console.log("update()");
                    // The least index series will be nearest the x-axis
                    var stackNumber = 0;
                    var numTweets = updateValues();
                    console.log(numTweets + "");
                    for (var i = 0, currentSeries = that.series; i < currentSeries.length; i++) {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = numTweets[i];

                        stackNumber += y;
                        currentSeries[i].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }
               }
          }
          // set up the updating of the chart each second
          var series = this.series[0];
          setInterval(update, 1000);
     }
}
```

(I'm probably missing some brace somewhere in the code-paste here, but I know for sure that my problem isn't related to a missing brace)

And here is the function that actually queries Twitter using a series of jQuery calls. The `updateValues()` function (which is outside the document-ready section) goes as follows:

```
    function updateValues() {
        var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=";
        var cls = "Penn_CIS240"
        var query = "%23" + cls;
        var voteCount = [0,0,0,0];

        // create an array of zeros
        //for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        //    voteCount.push(0);

        $.getJSON(url + query, function(json){
            console.log(json);
            $.each(json.results, function(i, tweet) {
                var user = tweet.from_user_id;

                if (user % 2 == 0) {
                    voteCount[0] += 1;
                }
                else if (user % 3 == 0) {
                    voteCount[1] += 1;
                }
                else if (user % 5 == 0) {
                    voteCount[2] += 1;
                }
                else {
                    voteCount[3] += 1;
                }
                console.log("updateValues() -> getJSON -> each -> voteCount = " + voteCount);
            });
            console.log("updateValues() -> getJSON -> voteCount = " + voteCount);
        });
        console.log("updateValues() -> voteCount = " + voteCount);

        return voteCount;
    }
```

What is happening is that the variable `voteCount` is getting incremented properly inside the jQuery calls. However, outside of the calls, it is getting reset. So the log outputs look something like this:

```
updateValues() -> getJSON -> each -> voteCount = [1,0,0,0]
updateValues() -> getJSON -> voteCount = [1,0,0,0]
updateValues() -> voteCount = [0,0,0,0]
```

Does this problem have to do with jQuery's asynchronous calls, and I'm having interesting variable modification conflicts? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use asynchronous callbacks in JavaScript, they execute later... asynchronously. So if you have:

```
var x = 5;
console.log("before getJSON", 5);
$.getJSON("/some/url", function (json) {
    x = 10;
    console.log("inside callback", x);
});
console.log("after getJSON", x);
```

the output will be

```
before getJSON 5
after getJSON 5
inside callback 10
```

Any code you want to execute after the request returns must be inside the callback; putting it physically "after" the `$.getJSON` call will not suffice. You should think of `$.getJSON` as "firing off" the JSON-getting process, then immediately returning to you; only later, when your script is done executing normal code and the server has responded, will the JavaScript event loop say "hey I got a response and am idle; time to call that callback that was waiting on the response!"

---

Because of this, your `updateValues` function will need to accept a callback of its own in order to notify its own caller that the values have been updated; just calling `updateValues` will only fire off the value-updating process, and the values won't be updated later until that idle time. Something like:

```
function updateValues(onUpdated) {
    var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=";
    var cls = "Penn_CIS240"
    var query = "%23" + cls;
    var voteCount = [0,0,0,0];

    $.getJSON(url + query, function (json) {
        // use of json to update voteCount ellided

        onUpdated(voteCount);
    });
}
```

Then calling code uses it as

```
updateValues(function (voteCount) {
    // use the updated vote counts inside here.
});
```

Comment: @GiantMarshmallow basically, add your `return voteCount;` inside your getJson block (where your second console.log is)

Comment: @roselan you cannot `return` a value for the outer function from inside a callback function.

Comment: ups true! however your solution seems strange, as the result is used to build the graph. can it refresh with this callback? Personnally, I would use a global variable for voteCount, set it with updateValues (called outside of the graph builder function), and let it refresh it within the setInterval. (Additionally, another global var "time" (getTime()) could be set in the .success function to keep consitancy)

Comment: @roselan: You can do anything, including refreshing, within a callback. Your solution uses two worst-practices (global variables, `setInterval` polling), and will not be as fast or responsive as the standard method (used by all libraries, as you can see by jQuery's `$.getJSON`) since it polls instead of responds to callbacks. For example if you used the same `setInterval` for updating as you did for sending the `$.getJSON` request, as you seem to be suggesting, there would be an extra one second delay.

Comment: thanx a lot (and sorry for hijaking this question)

Comment: Nope, you can pass anonymous functions to other functions, just like we did for `$.getJSON`. But it might make your code clearer, i.e. it just becomes `updateValues(onUpdate)` instead of `updateValues(function (voteCount) { ... })`

Comment: ps: my question (which I deleted before the answer) was: no need to create a 'onUploaded' function?